# How to convert an image in to 3d object - three.js

Tags: three.js

In my requirement, i need to show different building to user on mouse moments. ( like roaming a city ). I have no.of builidng as a photo. how to convert all those in to `3d` object?

a) I can trace (draw) using illustrator so the builidg became 2d drawing, but how to convert that in to `3d` object? and will `three.js` accept the `vector` drawing created out of it?

b) or can i directly use the different images to make an 3d view? if so, example i have front view and back view - how to convert them to `3d` image?

here is my sample image:
any one help me to showing, make this to `3d` and my camera let go around it?
I am looking for some good clue or sample works or tutorials.

[image: Sample Building]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_computer_graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Don't trace into a vector, it's going to be 2D if you do so. How would you roam a 2D image?

b) This approach beats the purpose of having a real 3D model instead of your the image plane, the result won't be convincing at all.

What you really need to do is the following:

1 - Like 2pha said, get your hands on some 3d modeling package such as 3dsmax or Maya (both paid), or you can use Blender, which is free and open-source. You need a 3d modeling package to recreate, or model, a 3d representation of that building (manually).

This process is very artistic, and requires good knowledge of the software. You'd be better off hiring someone who'd model the building(s) for you.

This video showcases how a 2d image is recreated in 3d:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnfVrP6L89M

2 - Once the 3d models of the building(s) are created, you need to export them to a format that three.js understands, such as .fbx or .obj

3 - Now, you'd have to import the .obj or .fbx file with your building into three.js

4 - Implement the controls and other requirements.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need to model it in a 3d modelling program such as 3ds Max, then export it to use in three.js. The closest thing that I know that can convert images int a model is [123d](http://www.123dapp.com/). You really need to search google for such a vague question like this.

Comment: @EnterpriseArchitect 2pha didn't just say "google it". He googled it himself and shared the results.